# Call to undefined function getRequiredMarker() - CiViCRM

Tags: civievent, drupal

I have setup CiViCRM with Drupal. Setup was completed successfully without any errors.

After Login into Drupal as Admin, while I'm visiting new event create page  using menu -> Events -> New Event, I got blank page nothing else.

When I checked the error log it says:

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function getRequiredMarker() in /var/www/html/xx-civicrm/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%89/896/89673E6E%%ProfileTemplates.tpl.php on line 64, referer: http://xxxxxxx.com/civicrm?reset=1**

But I found that function "getRequiredMarker()" in a js file:

/sites/all/modules/civicrm/js/view/crm.designer.js

So what is the issue here? What is the solution here?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue:

It is because of **asp_tags** extension. Need to turn off it.

Either turn off it from php.ini file(globally disable)

OR

by putting this line in .htaccess file(locally disable)

php_flag asp_tags off